# HDFS / Hive / Spark Integration test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, integration-testing

Consider the following scenario with the following steps:

1. Load a csv file into HDFS
2. Read this file using Spark
3. Transform it
4. Persist it to Hive
5. Query it using SparkSQL

What is the best approach doing it in Scala? Which libraries can help with this integration testing?

Comment: CSV could be replaced with an in memory list, and HDFS is not required, the interface works the same for local FS. You can look at the existing Spark code that already checks the Hive integration or the dataframe writer

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/Landoop/coyote It's quite heavy tool, but that tool makes it possible to write just such test scripts in yaml.